# Convert Pandas Dataframe to JSON format: how to group

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas Dataframe:

```
     nodes        x      y        z
0        1   0.0000  0.000   0.0000
1        2   0.0000  9.144   0.0000
2        3  19.5072  0.000   0.0000
3        4  19.5072  9.144   0.0000
4        5   9.7536  0.000   0.0000
..     ...      ...    ...      ...
175    176  19.5072  9.144  27.7368
176    177  19.5072  9.144  25.7556
177    178  19.5072  9.144  21.7932
178    179  19.5072  9.144  19.8120
179    180  19.5072  9.144  17.8308
```

to convert to JSON:

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "1": {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        },
        "2": {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 9.144,
            "z": 0
        },
        "3": {
            "x": 19.5072,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        },
        "4": {
            "x": 19.5072,
            "y": 9.144,
            "z": 0
        },
        "5": {
            "x": 9.7536,
            "y": 0,
            "z": 0
        },
    },
}
```

I just started to use python. After Google, I tried:

```
out = df.to_json(orient = 'records')
print(json.dumps(json.loads(out), indent=4))
```

It resulted in:

```
{
    "nodes": 1,
    "x": 0.0,
    "y": 0.0,
    "z": 0.0
},
{
    "nodes": 2,
    "x": 0.0,
    "y": 9.144,
    "z": 0.0
},
{
    "nodes": 3,
    "x": 19.5072,
    "y": 0.0,
    "z": 0.0
},
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `groupby` function to achieve your desired output:

```
out = {'nodes': df.groupby('nodes').last().to_dict(orient='index')}
print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))
```

Results in:

```
{
    "nodes": {
        "1": {
            "x": 0.0,
            "y": 0.0,
            "z": 0.0
        },
        "2": {
            "x": 0.0,
            "y": 9.144,
            "z": 0.0
        },
        "3": {
            "x": 19.5072,
            "y": 0.0,
            "z": 0.0
        },
        "4": {
            "x": 19.5072,
            "y": 9.144,
            "z": 0.0
        },
        "5": {
            "x": 9.7536,
            "y": 0.0,
            "z": 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ drec4s. It works. Thank you. Could you please tell the function `.last()`?

Comment: `out = {'nodes': df.groupby('nodes').last().to_dict(orient='index')}` worked; otherwise, you will get a warning `FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.`